# Java - How to read only certain parts of an input stream

Tags: java, file, io

I have a requirement where i need to parse an input file and read only certain parts of the file. I have a an log file which has different levels like info warning and error. Now i need to read only the parts which contains the full error stack trace. How can i achieve this using java.

Ex:

```
INFO  | 2011-04-13 17:59:22,810 | Calling Feedback from 127.0.0.1 
INFO  | 2011-04-13 17:59:24,920 | Successfully called Feedback from 127.0.0.1
INFO  | 2011-04-13 17:59:31,561 | FeedBackList

ERROR | 2011-04-13 19:00:41,640 |  
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:228)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor.invoke(HibernateInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy309.getConsumerProfileData(Unknown Source)
    at com.scea.usps.model.service.impl.AccountSettingsServiceImpl.getUserProfile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor.invoke(HibernateInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy284.getUserProfile(Unknown Source)
    at com.scea.usps.model.common.PsninfoUtility.getTop3Generes(Unknown Source)
    at com.scea.usps.model.common.PsninfoUtility.updatePsnInfoDetail(Unknown Source)
    at com.scea.platform.framework.api.PsnInfoThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

INFO  | 2011-04-13 17:59:22,810 | Calling Feedback from 127.0.0.1 
INFO  | 2011-04-13 17:59:24,920 | Successfully called Feedback from 127.0.0.1
INFO  | 2011-04-13 17:59:31,561 | FeedBackList
```

In the above log i need to extract(read) all lines starting from ERROR till the stack trace ends. Please share your ideas on this. Thanks.

Comment: When you say "read only certain parts of the file" do you mean you need to parse those FROM the file? What i'm asking is are you just looking for an algorithm to parse the appropriate data, or something more complex?

Also, will all "ERRORS" have stack traces? Are the only beginning entries of a line ERROR/INFO and newlines?

If this is just a basic "how do I..." question, then Brian's answer below makes the most sense.

Comment: Why does the log file parser have to be Java?

Comment: Not sure if Chainsaw, http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html, can handle this out of the box but i can be worth a try before building your own application.

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("logfile.log"));
  String line = in.readLine();
  StringBuffer buf = null;
  while (line != null) {
    if(line.startsWith("ERROR")){
       buf = new StringBuffer();
       buf.append(line).append("\n");
       while(line != null && !line.trim().equals("")){
          line = in.readLine();
          buf.append(line).append("\n");
       }
       //Now buf has your error an do whatever you want to do with it
       //then delete
       buf = null;
    }
    line = in.readLine();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It doesnt work. I need to print not just the 1st line of the error stack trace but i also need to print the remaining lines of the error stack trace.

Comment: @Hitatichi: My solution saves on the StringBuffer all the lines between "ERROR ..." and the blank line, so this also save the stack trace that you want

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to watch your application's logs for errors, then a tool like [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw) may be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Chainsaw does have this built-in, if you use a LogFilePatternReceiver.  You can define a filterExpression, and only events matching that filterexpression will be processed.

An example filter expression that will only include stack traces would be:

exception exists

You do have to provide the format of your log file.  See the JavaDoc for more info:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/receivers/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LogFilePatternReceiver.html

Answer (score 0):

- Open File
- Read until you hit the line with ERROR
- Read and process lines until you hit the blank line after the stack trace.

Rinse, Repeat.

Comment: @mike Yes i am just looking for an algorithm to parse the required parts from a huge log file. Yes all the errors will have stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
      BufferedReader in
          = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("logfile.log"));
      String line = in.readLine();
      while (!line.startsWith("ERROR")) {
        line = in.readLine();
        if(line==null){
          //throw exception here, ERROR not found in entire log file
        }
      }
      //HERE line will be your error line
      while (line!=null) {
        line = in.readLine();
        //do something with line
      }
      //here you have reached the end of the file
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the propmpt reply. But what happens to the lines following the ERROR line. Even those lines need to printed along with the Error line. Please guide me in the right direction. Thanks.